# How to manually set IP to Request Object in Laravel for testing

Tags: laravel-5

I need to set IP address on laravel requests for testing.

I don't want to mock Request.

Please, help.

This is how I'm getting IP in a controller

```
$request = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request);
$ip      = $request->ip();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$request->server->add(['REMOTE_ADDR' => '0.0.0.0']);
```

Answer (score 5):

When inside a phpunit test class, I was able to override the users IP for testing laravel like so:

```
public function testPathWithInternalIp() {
    $this->serverVariables = ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '192.168.1.1'];

    $response = $this->get('/some-path');
}
```

`'/some-path'` will get accessed as if it was a user on 192.168.1.1, so if you have behaviour that is different you can then assert that condition on the `$response`.

Comment: Does this variable keep it's value in the next unit test?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev the serverVariables array is reset for every test.

Answer (score 2):

When testing, you can call the `withServerVariables(...)` method to provide additional server variables.

Calling the following method (before example a get request) will change the request IP-address:

```php
$this
    ->withServerVariables(['REMOTE_ADDR' => '0.0.0.0'])
    ->get('/some-path');
```